# How to nullify the /var/log/message file as a normal user

Tags: linux, null

Is it possible to truncate the `/var/log/messages` file as a normal user? If yes what permissions do we need to mention in `sudoers` file for this?

Answer (score 1):

Since this is about accessing files, the filesystem permissions would be the better tool for this job.

You could create an user group like `logadmins` (or use an existing group like `sudo`, `wheel` or possibly `staff` or `adm` if it's already used for the exact set of users you wish to grant this permission to), then adjust the permissions of the `/var/log/message` file to be writeable by that group. Then you can just add the users to that group if they need to be able to do this task.

Then the normal user that belongs to the correct group will be able to just do it without `sudo` or any other special tool.

But it might be a better idea to automate this task using `logrotate` or similar tool. Many distributions already have a `logrotate` configuration that covers `/var/log/messages`: if it does not run frequently enough for you, you should adjust its schedule to suit your needs.

And if the actual problem is that your logs are being flooded with useless debug logging that you don't want, try finding the source of the useless messages and stopping them there, e.g. by adjusting the application's logging settings to only log the kind of things you actually *need* to log.